# Using the BSD 3-clause license with splash screen

Tags: software, licensing

If someone is using a BSD 3-clause licensed software in their own product, what would be considered "endorse or "promote". The license states:

> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
>      this software without specific prior written permission.

Would the developer be able to add something like a splash screen in a video game with the software's name? So as the game is loading the different software used to create it would be displayed to the user or would that be considered an implied "endorsement" from the software's creators?

Comment: This clause is talking about the names of copyright holders, i.e. persons. It doesn't say anything about using the names of software programs e.g. in a splash screen.